# Value type reallocation

Tags: swift

Consider I have a struct **Person** with a property "**name**". Why changing the name property results in a new memory address?

```
struct Person {
    var name = "Alex"
}

var person = Person()
withUnsafePointer(to: person) { print($0)
} // 0x000000016fdff248

person.name = "John"
withUnsafePointer(to: person) { print($0)
} // 0x000000016fdff208
```

Comment: But to answer your question you can read : https://itwenty.me/2020/08/exploring-memory-layout-and-pointers-in-swift/

Comment: I mistyped let with var.

Comment: `withUnsafePointer` may or may not copy the value to a separate location at each call. You may even get different addresses *without* mutating the structure. It also depends on whether you compile in Debug and Release mode.

Comment: The key here is that a struct is a value type, like an Int. Structs are not promised to have addresses. What is the address of the value `4`? (Int is a struct in Swift, just like Person.) It is possible that there is an address as an implementation detail, and when you call `withUnsafePointer(to:)`, you force an address to temporarily exist, but that may require allocating memory and copying the value. As a practical, implementation matter, when you mutate structs, they may be copied (though they may not be). And passing it to `withUnsafePointer` may copy (as MartinR notes).

Comment: Try this program: `var int = 4; withUnsafePointer(to: int) { print($0) }; withUnsafePointer(to: int) { print($0) }`. It also prints different values. You don't need mutation or even a custom struct to get different addresses printed. (I'm certain this is a duplicate question, I just can't find the right one to dupe it to.)

Comment: @RobNapier: I also thought this has been asked before, but could not find it. Perhaps you want to write an answer?

Comment: @RobNapier: Btw, top-level and static variables do have a guaranteed address. It took me a while to find where I had read that, but here it is: https://forums.swift.org/t/lazyweb-citation-for-stored-globals-have-stable-addresses/40451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the wrong version of `withUnsafePointer(to:)`. If you call the right one, it behaves as you expect (though it is not promised to do so). The one you're calling is:

```
func withUnsafePointer<T, Result>(to value: T, _ body: (UnsafePointer<T>) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

That passes a copy of `value` to the function. It doesn't even require that there be memory allocated; it'll allocate memory itself to ensure that there's something to point to:

```
// Who needs a variable?
withUnsafePointer(to: 4) { print($0) }  // 0x000000016fdff348 
withUnsafePointer(to: 4) { print($0) }  // 0x000000016fdff340
```

But there's also an `inout` version of this function, and I expect it's what you really meant to call:

```
func withUnsafePointer<T, Result>(to value: inout T, _ body: (UnsafePointer<T>) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

That expects a *reference* to the value. Note the use of `&` here, and that it behaves as you're expecting:

```swift
var person = Person()
withUnsafePointer(to: &person) { print($0) } // 0x0000000100008018

person.name = "John"
withUnsafePointer(to: &person) { print($0) } // 0x0000000100008018
```

Do not read too much into this. The compiler [does not promise](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0205-withUnsafePointer-for-lets.md) stable addresses [except in very specific cases](https://forums.swift.org/t/kvo-context-param/4203) as MartinR noted. There is no safe way to hold onto a pointer to a struct (and references are not quite the same thing as pointers in any case). Structs are not even promised to allocate memory. Every Int is a struct, after all. But if you use the `inout` version of this call, I think the mystery disappears.

Comment: The behaviour of `withUnsafePointer` is also stated in https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0205-withUnsafePointer-for-lets.md: “It is unspecified whether taking a pointer to the same variable or property produces a consistent pointer value across different withUnsafePointer/Bytes calls.”